# .Net maui control template border has buttons inside it but the do not execute the command

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, maui

how are you ? I'm developing an application in .NET MAUI (I'm kind of new to net maui), and I'm creating a custom control, which consists of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Controls.DashboardItemBoxView">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border 
                Margin="10" 
                BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding ContentViewColor}">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Border.Shadow>
                    <Shadow
                        Brush="{TemplateBinding ContentViewColor}"
                        Offset="0,8"
                        Opacity="0.5"               
                        Radius="50">
                    </Shadow>
                </Border.Shadow>

                <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid x:Name="titleGrid" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image 
                            WidthRequest="{TemplateBinding IconFontSize}" HeightRequest="{TemplateBinding IconFontSize}"
                            MaximumWidthRequest="50" MinimumWidthRequest="50">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <FontImageSource                                 
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding IconFontFamily}"
                                    Glyph="{TemplateBinding IconFont}"             
                                    Color="{x:StaticResource IconFontColor}"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>

                        <Label  Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                FontSize="15" 
                                TextColor="{TemplateBinding TitleForeColor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    
                    <ContentPresenter  
                        Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding ContentViewColor}"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                       
                        />

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>

</ContentView>
```

Within the  I am sending buttons which each one has a command assigned in its view model, that is, the code that implements my custom control is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.General.Dashboards.EmployeeAdministratorDashboardPage"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Controls"
             Title="Administracion"
             BackgroundColor="White">

        <Grid>
            
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="titleRow" Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="productDivisionRow" Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="productItemsRow" Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Gestion de Administrador" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="30" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Gray"/>
       
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <myControls:DashboardItemBoxView 
                    Title="Productos" 
                    TitleForeColor="White" 
                    ContentViewColor="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                    IconFont="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.InboxArrowUp}"
                    IconFontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                    IconFontColor="White"
                    IconFontSize="24">

                    <HorizontalStackLayout >
                        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">
                            <Button
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    IsEnabled="True">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource 
                                        FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                        Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.PlusBox}"             
                                        Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                        Size="20" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>

                            <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding goCrudProductPageCommand}"/>
                            </Button.GestureRecognizers>
                                
                            </Button>
                            <Label 
                                    Text="Registro" 
                                    FontSize="14" 
                                    TextColor="White"/>

                        </VerticalStackLayout>

                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">

                            <Button
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    Command="{Binding goScanBarCodeProductPageCommand}">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource 
                                    FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                    Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Scanner}"             
                                    Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                    Size="20" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>
                            </Button>

                            <Label Text="Escanear" FontSize="14" TextColor="White"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </myControls:DashboardItemBoxView>

            <myControls:DashboardItemBoxView 
                    Title="Empleados" 
                    TitleForeColor="White" 
                    ContentViewColor="{x:StaticResource OrangeCardProducts}"
                    IconFont="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.InboxArrowUp}"
                    IconFontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                    IconFontColor="White"
                    IconFontSize="24">

                <HorizontalStackLayout >
                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">
                        <Button
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    IsEnabled="True">
                            <Button.ImageSource>
                                <FontImageSource 
                                        FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                        Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.PlusBox}"             
                                        Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                        Size="20" />
                            </Button.ImageSource>

                            <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding goCrudProductPageCommand}"/>
                            </Button.GestureRecognizers>

                        </Button>
                        <Label 
                                    Text="Registro" 
                                    FontSize="14" 
                                    TextColor="White"/>

                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">

                        <Button
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    Command="{Binding goScanBarCodeProductPageCommand}">
                            <Button.ImageSource>
                                <FontImageSource 
                                    FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcons"
                                    Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Scanner}"             
                                    Color="{x:StaticResource StoreSysPrimaryColor}"
                                    Size="20" />
                            </Button.ImageSource>
                        </Button>

                        <Label Text="Escanear" FontSize="14" TextColor="White"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </myControls:DashboardItemBoxView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

view model of my content page (which calls my custom control)

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Extensions;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Services.App.Navegation;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Shared;
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products;
using static StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Products.ScanBarCodeProductViewModel;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.General.Management
{
    public partial class EmployeeAdministratorDashboardViewModel : GlobalViewModel
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task goScanBarCodeProductPage()
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"scanOperation" , SCAN_OPERATION.READ_PRODUCT }
            };
            var uri = $"{nameof(ScanBarcodeProductPage)}";
            await ServiceLocator.GetService<INavigationService>().GoToAsync(uri, parameters);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task goCrudProductPage()
        {

            var uri = $"{nameof(CRUDProductPage)}";
            await ServiceLocator.GetService<INavigationService>().GoToAsync(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, now, the problem is that when I click or touch my phone with my finger, the button does nothing, that is, the command that binds to the button is never invoked, instead it is in my custom control.  I take out the '
Grid.Row="1" ', the button is clicked and works fine, can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: What's the  code of `DashboardItemBoxView.xaml.cs` and `GlobalViewModel`? If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: A good idea when learning to do something new, is to split the tasks into very small portions of work. When I was learning control templates, I created a template with a single button inside, and one bindable property - command. I did not write 10 pages of code with the hope that everything will start to work just like that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, you can solve it by creating a Collection view, and I tapped gesture recognized to the collectionviewitem, this way it worked for me!
Thanks for the support!